# How do I prove $\int_{0}^{2a}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx +\int_{0}^{a}f(2a-x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck on this one. I was able to prove  $\int_{0}^{a}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(a-x)dx $
just by using substitution with $t = a - x$, but I'm not sure about this one. I've tried quite a few subsitutions, such as $t = 2a - x$, but none seem to work?

Comment: You should be able to see this geometrically. After this step, the algebraic proof makes no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On one hand, 
$$\tag{1}\int_{0}^{2a}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx +\int_{a}^{2a}f(x)dx.$$
On the other hand, 
if we consider 
$\displaystyle\int_{a}^{2a}f(x)dx,$
using substitution $y=2a-x$, then we have 
$$\tag{2}\int_{a}^{2a}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{0}f(2a-y)(-dy)=\int_0^af(2a-y)dy.$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get the required expression.

Comment: I feel silly asking this but I can follow (2), but I still don't understand where you get the expression in (1), do u just see that as an intuitive thing? Is it the geometry of the expression?

Comment: This is the way for me to get $(1)$: Since we want to get $\int_{0}^{2a}f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{a}f(x)dx +\int_{0}^{a}f(2a-x)dx$, therefore I try to write $\int_{0}^{2a}f(x) dx$ as $(1)$. The first term on the RHS in $(1)$ is exactly the first term of the required expression. So I try to rewrite the second term on the RHS of $(1)$ to get the required expression.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is spot on. Letting $u=2a-x$ gives $$du=-dx\qquad u(0)=2a\qquad u(a)=a $$ This implies
$$
\int_0^a f(2a-x)\,dx=-\int_{2a}^af(u)\,du
$$
Can you finish the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like posted before using the variable u=2a-x will solve your problem. I think the trick here is to start by the result and try to find the first expression. It's pretty immediate that way. 
You always have the possibility to present it the other way around so it looks like you solved the problem as asked.