# On the way of evaluate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+2\sin^{2}x}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+2\sin^2x}$$

My approach
$$\Longrightarrow\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{1+2\sin^{2}x}=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sec^{2}x}{1+3\tan^{2}x}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\tan x\right)\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
$\tan x$ is undefined at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

So I need to solve $\lim_{x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}}$$\left[\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\tan x\right)\right]$. I don't know how to solve.

Comment: See also: [Evaluating $\int\limits_0^{\pi} \frac{dx}{1+2\sin^2x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/958920). Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B1%2B2%5Csin%5E%7B2%7Dx%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Brother i wasn't aware of Aproach0 when i posted this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that as $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\sqrt{3}\tan(x) \to \infty$, therefore $\tan^{-1}(\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2}$